# object-fit:cover resizes img width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a carousel slide, but when I'm using `object-fit:cover` and adding the second image the first and the second image width are changing from 100% to 50%

on 1 input it works fine
[See photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4XBN.png)

on second input it's changing its width
[See photo2 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o9Y0.png)

Comment: From the behavior, it looks like your parent component is flex. If so, this is how flex works.
If not - provide mode details.

Comment: yes you are right, parent is flex and when I'm adding transform:translateX(100%) the whole container is going to the right...

Answer (score 0):

I think the `object-fit:cover` property can be set with the `width` property.

```
image {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Then the image places appropriately so that it's width is 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want img to be 100% in flex layout you can use one of these options:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

img {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

If smth else - update/improve your question